# Glsl Matrix Registers?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I remember reading that mat4x3 took more registers, as it has four columns, than a mat3x4 even though they have the same number of elements. I can't seem to find this anywhere anymore. Does the new spec use the same number of uniform registers for both types of matrices?

Is there any performance hit with transpose as well?

```
mat3x4 a; // transposed mat4x3

result = transpose(a) * vec4(val, 1); // keeps order
result = vec4(val, 1) * a; // better performance?
```

Assuming (i think) they do the samething.

Comment: Nowadays most of GPUs are scalar so I think you are right - its gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the latest (4.4) spec document, uniform limits are expressed in components. Talking about `MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS` and equivalent limits for other shader stages that can be queried with `glGetIntegerv()`:

> These values represent the numbers of individual ﬂoating-point, integer, or boolean values that can be held in uniform variable storage for a shader.

Then later, about matrices:

> A matrix uniform will consume no more than 4 × min(r,c) components, where r and c are the number of rows and columns in the matrix.

So for `mat3x4` and `mat4x3`, the minimum dimension is 3 both times, so the number of components consumed will be 12 for both.

The older style capacity queries are still there, but the definition looks like they were mainly maintained for backwards compatibility:

> The implementation-dependent constants MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS and MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_VECTORS have values respectively equal to the values of MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS and MAX_FRAGMENT_UNIFORM_COMPONENTS divided by four.

Note that attributes, unlike uniforms, are still vector oriented. According to table 11.2, a `mat3x4` consumes 3 attribute slots, while a `mat4x3` consumes 4 attribute slots.